# How to get the closest Textfield's value after clicking on a Checkbox - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, closest

I'm trying to get the closest Textfield's Value after checking a checkbox. This is just a simple HTML example. In my project I have dynamically added Lists with multiple checkboxes. I always need the closest Textfield's value - something like a refenrence that shows that hte checkbox and the textfield belongs together. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='oberpunkte' name='checkbox' value='typo 3'/>
<input type='text' name='text' value='typo3txt'/>
<input type='button' name='test' id='123' value='Alert'/>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#123").click(function(){
$('input:checkbox[class=oberpunkte]:checked').each(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('input[type=text]').attr('value'));
    });
});
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pEb7D/1/

Comment: `$(this).next('input[type=text]').attr('value')` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pEb7D/3/)

Comment: In this case you want to use siblings http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Dhaval Marthak's solution worked for me. @RobSchmuecker Is there any advantages prefering siblings instead of next() ?

Comment: Yes, siblings matches before and after. If your HTML is always like above then `next()` will work just fine.  However if your text box were to move `before` the checkbox then next will stop working for that checkbox and end up getting the one in the next row!

Comment: why closest() is not working ?

Comment: @MaheshReddy because .closest() is going up trough the DOM. So kind if you click on a child you will find its closest parent (but here is no parent) http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: I can't get the value of the textfields I added dynamically via Button click. Even if they are similar to the previos Textfields.... Any Ideas to solve this?

Comment: OK fixed it by changing the code to "alert($(this).closest('input[type=text]').val());"

Comment: @Preprocezzor it's a long time since. You may want to accept an answer?

Comment: @caramba sure man, thanks for helping me out 6 years ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would be "nicer" if you wrap your html in a `<div class="box">` but like what you have it you can use prev or next depending where the click happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/pEb7D/4/

```
$(".oberpunkte").change(function(){
      alert($(this).next('input').val())
});

$('#123').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).prev('input').val());
});
```

**UPDATE with a div.box as parent**
In my opinion this is a nicer solution. Cause doesn't matter where you click we can check from `$(this)`where is the closest box and then get the value we're looking for...

http://jsfiddle.net/pEb7D/7/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#123, .oberpunkte").on('click', function(){
          alert($(this).closest('.box').children('.needToFind').val())
    });
</script>

<div class="box">
    <input type='checkbox' class='oberpunkte' name='checkbox' value='typo 3'/>
    <input class="needToFind" type='text' name='text' value='typo3txt'/>
    <input type='button' name='test' id='123' value='Alert'/>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <input type='checkbox' class='oberpunkte' name='checkbox' value='typo 3'/>
    <input class="needToFind" type='text' name='text' value='123456'/>
    <input type='button' name='test' id='123' value='Alert'/>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <input type='checkbox' class='oberpunkte' name='checkbox' value='typo 3'/>
    <input class="needToFind" type='text' name='text' value='xxxxxx'/>
    <input type='button' name='test' id='123' value='Alert'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using parent() and find(), than make a connection between them, so if you future html changes you would not need to change the javascript.

```
$("#123").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('selectorToInput').DO_STUFF;
}
```